# Disable arrow keys in insert mode

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to disable the arrow keys in the vimrc (previously I was doing it by doing a no-op on the keyboard itself):

```
"Disable arrow keys
inoremap <Left> <Nop>
```

However, it seems to be doing nothing, as it seems like the actual keyboard code sent for an arrow key (using insert, ctrl-v) is:

```
^[OD
```

So, is there a way to disable the arrow keys from within vim? Or does this need to be done outside it?

Comment: Does [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5851/how-to-disable-arrow-keys-in-vim) answer yours?

Comment: @Biggybi -- no. I'm already doing `noremap <Up> <Nop>`, and wondering why that's not working, etc.

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but you could always remap them to, say, `<c-o>echo "Nice try!"<cr>`

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your `inoremap <Left> <Nop>` works for me in terminal and gui in Vim 8.2 (linux).

Comment: Your mapping should work correctly I also reproduce it in a Vim 8.0 and neovim 0.4.3. I think you might be interested in [how to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) and maybe also [how to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)